# How to apply same VBA code to multiple files in a folder?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an operation that I need to apply on up to 1000 files in a folder.

As output, two files will be created in a separate folder from each file which need to be processed. The code works on a single file, however, the output files come up as empty Excel tables when the code is applied on multiple files.

```vb
Sub wB_postup_test_all_files()
    
    Dim MyFile As String, Str As String, MyDir As String, Wb As Workbook
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    'change the address to suite
    
    MyDir = "Some directory here"
    MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xlsx")
    ChDir MyDir
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = 0
    
    Do While MyFile <> ""
        Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
        
    'where core operation starts
    
    Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(2).EntireColumn.Delete
    Rows(1).Insert
    
    Range("B1") = "=AVERAGE(B3:B4724)"
    Range("A:A").Copy Range("D:D")
    Range("B:B").Copy Range("E:E")
    Range("D1") = "prumer"
    Range("E2") = Range("B2").Value + "-prum"
    Range("E1") = ""
    Range("E3").Select
        
        Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Value = ""
    
        myCell0 = Range("B1").Value
        myCell1 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value
    
            If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) = True Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "nic"
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Else
            ActiveCell.Value = myCell1 - myCell0
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
                    
        Loop
        
    Range("D:D").Copy Range("G:G")
    Range("E:E").Copy
    Range("H:H").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("H2").Select
    
        Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Value = ""
        
            If ActiveCell.Value = "nic" Then
            ActiveCell.Clear
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
        
        Loop
    
    ActiveCell.Clear
    
    'plotting the scatter graph
    
    Range("G3").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Range("G3:H4724").Select
    Range("G4724").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("G3:H4724")
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = Range("H2").Value
        
    ActiveChart.Parent.Cut
    Range("I4712").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Range("I4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("I3").Select
        
        'saving some columns as separate file
        
        Dim Path As String
        filename = Range("B2").Value
        Path = "Some path here"
        
        With Workbooks.Add
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("G:G").Copy .Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("H:H").Copy .Sheets(1).Range("B1")
        .SaveAs filename:=Path & filename & "-prum.xlsx"
        .Close
        End With
    
    Sheets.Add.Name = "2"
    
    Sheet1.Range("G:G").Copy Worksheets("2").Range("A1")
    Sheet1.Range("H:H").Copy Worksheets("2").Range("B1")
    Worksheets("2").Activate
    Range("B1").Value = "=STDEVP(B3:B4724)"
    Range("A:A").Copy Range("D:D")
    Range("B:B").Copy Range("E:E")
    Range("D1") = "prumer"
    Range("E3").Select
    
        Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Value = ""
    
        myCell0 = Range("B1").Value
        myCell1 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value
    
            If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) = True Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "nic"
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Else
            ActiveCell.Value = myCell1 - myCell0
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
                    
        Loop
        
    Range("D:D").Copy Range("G:G")
    Range("E:E").Copy
    Range("H:H").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("H2").Select
    
        Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Value = ""
        
            If ActiveCell.Value = "nic" Then
            ActiveCell.Clear
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
        
        Loop
    
    ActiveCell.Clear
    Range("E1").Clear
    Range("H1").Clear
    
    'plotting the scatter graph
    
    Range("G3").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Range("G3:H4724").Select
    Range("G4724").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("G3:H4724")
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = Range("H2").Value
        
    ActiveChart.Parent.Cut
    Range("I4712").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Range("I4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("I3").Select
    
    'saving some columns as separate file
        
        
        With Workbooks.Add
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("G:G").Copy .Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("H:H").Copy .Sheets(1).Range("B1")
        .SaveAs filename:=Path & filename & "-prum ku SD.xlsx"
        .Close
        End With
    
    'where core opreation ends
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.Close True
        MyFile = Dir()
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, no need to select anything in your code. Secondly, you should fully qualify the sheets you are processing. `ChDir MyDir` is useless. The iteration between folder files works the same without it. Be sure that `Path` ends in "\". Then, `Application.ScreenUpdating = 0` and `Application.DisplayAlerts = 0` not only are useless, they do not let you see what is happening on the sheet. All used variable must previously be declared. Try using `Option Explicit` on top of the module where the code exists (in the declarations area). In this way, VBA will warn you if a variable is not declared.

Answer (score 1):

Not easy to learn vba by putting the pieces together as their are so much bad examples out their.

The basic idea is to minimise the number of interactions with the sheet as these will dramatically slow down performance. VBA is on it's best when you work in memory and working in memory means learning to use arrays.
Additionally you will ease your problem solving by splitting your code in smaller pieces by using functions and subs.

Concerning your "blank" export it's maybe due to this part:

```
    With Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("G:G").Copy .Sheets(1).Range("A1")
```

you are exporting data from the sheet in which you run the macro, not the file you edited before.

Nevertheless, if you want to learn I refactored part of your code to give you an example on how it could look like in using multiple subs/functions and arrays. only writing to the sheet when all transformations are done.

```
    Option Explicit
    
    Sub files()
        'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
        Dim MyPath As String, BaseWks As Worksheet
            MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test\"
            
        'open files
        Dim FilesInPath As String, mybook As Workbook
            FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xlsx")
            Do While FilesInPath <> ""
                Set mybook = Nothing
                Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & FilesInPath)
                
            'build array & close WB
               Dim arr
               arr = Data(mybook)
            
            'export array
                Call Export(arr)
                
            'reset vars
                FilesInPath = Dir()
            Loop
    End Sub
    
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Supporting subs & functions of this module
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Function Data(mybook As Workbook) As Variant 'use a function when you want the output to be returned to your main sub
        'sheets in source workbooks
            Dim SourceWs As Worksheet
            Set SourceWs = mybook.Sheets(1)
            
        'data from source workbooks
            Dim arr
                SourceWs.Rows(1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown 'insert blank row
                arr = SourceWs.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(0, 2).Value2 'get data but remove col A, B
                     
        'Modify array
            Dim j As Long
                arr(1, 2) = "=AVERAGE(B3:B4724)" 'B1 value
                
                For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
                    arr(j, 4) = arr(j, 1) 'cold A to D
                    arr(j, 5) = arr(j, 2) 'cold B to E
                Next j
                
                arr(1, 4) = "prumer" 'd1
                arr(1, 5) = "" 'e1
                arr(2, 5) = arr(2, 2) & "-prum" 'e2
        
        'dump to sheet
            With SourceWs
                .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents 'clear old content
                .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2))) = arr 'dumb modified arr to sheet
            End With
            mybook.Close savechanges:=True 'close the file
        
        Data = arr 'return the modified array to the main sub, assuming it's this data that you want to export to a new workbook.
    End Function
    
    Private Sub Export(arr As Variant) 'use a sub when you just want to do something without returning output to the main sub
            Dim Newwb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, exportArr, Filename, j As Long
                'arr
                    ReDim exportArr(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 2) 'scale exportArr
                    Filename = "\" & CStr(arr(2, 2))
                    For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
                            exportArr(j, 1) = arr(j, 7) 'cold G to A
                            exportArr(j, 2) = arr(j, 8) 'cold H to B
                    Next j
                
                Set Newwb = Workbooks.Add
                With Newwb.ActiveSheet
                    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(exportArr), UBound(exportArr, 2))).Value2 = exportArr
                    .SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & Filename & "-prum2.xlsx" ', FileFormat:=xlsx, Local:=True 'save
                End With
                Newwb.Close savechanges:=False 'close the file
    End Sub
```

Don't hesitate if you have questions.